# How to prevent Service from being destroyed before it finishes its work

Tags: android

How do I keep a service from being destroyed before it finishes its work?  I'm using [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) to insure that the device doesn't fall asleep while the work is being done.  But I'm not sure this will even work.  In one particular place I'm creating a MediaPlayer to play a sound, but after working a few times I start getting exceptions about the thread being dead, and looking in the log I see that the service's onDestruct function is being called before the media player has a chance to do its work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In one particular place I'm creating a MediaPlayer to play a sound

Any form of `IntentService` is not suitable for that scenario. An `IntentService` is destroyed once `onHandleIntent()` returns (or, in the case of `WakefulIntentService`, when `doWakefulWork()` returns). Do not do anything in an `IntentService` that will last beyond the `onHandleIntent()` call.

Instead, use a regular `Service`, where you manage your own `WakeLock`, releasing it and stopping the service when the media playback is completed (via an `OnCompletionListener`).

(and, FWIW, I would recommend `JobIntentService` over my `WakefulIntentService`, for scenarios where a wakeful `IntentService` is the appropriate solution)

Comment: Interesting.  I somehow was under the impression that WakefulIntentService was the ticket to not having to manage the WakeLock myself...

Comment: @Michael: Well, `WakefulIntentService` manages the `WakeLock`, but it is still an `IntentService` at its core. Your problem is not the `Wakeful` part, but the `IntentService` part.

Comment: Ah I see my problem... I was using an old version of WakefulIntentService which extended Service, not IntentService.

Comment: @Michael: I don't recall writing one like that, so perhaps you are using somebody else's class. Regardless, you want to keep your service running until the media is done being played back. On Android 8.0+, that may be a problem if the media is longer than a minute.

Comment: I'm sure it's yours, it's got the string  "com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.WakefulIntentService" in it!  I think I may have done a copy/paste from a blog post or something you wrote a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Foreground Service` but the trade-off will be you will have to show a `foreground notification` in Android `status bar`, OR you can use `JobIntentService` which is same as intentservice but instead of running the service directly it uses Jobs to run the service.